# Not able to store NSDate in realm

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I know very basic question but am really struggling to do it. Please help me.

I have a realm object with `NSDate` datatype properties.
But how to insert date in that column.

```
class Log : Object
{

    dynamic var id : Int = 0
    dynamic var icn : Int64 = 0
    dynamic var status : String = ""
    dynamic var date : String = ""
    dynamic var timeIn = NSData()
    dynamic var timeOut = NSDate()
    dynamic var pauseAt = NSDate()
    dynamic var breakTime : Int = 0
    dynamic var spentMinutes : Int = 0
    dynamic var lati : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var longi : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var synced = false


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to declare the date this way, try to be more specific. How do you try to store it?

Comment: if you need to store NSData, I think is better to store NSData on disk and store just path string to this file.

Comment: @Idan am really sorry I've corona backgrond am learning & doing things. And so far so good, but am really confused in NSDate documentation.
I don't know how to get today's date & store it in realm.

Comment: @AbuEesa you are doing it!? NSDate() initialize the value for *now*. You can use Date() in Swift 3

Comment: @idan plz give me an example how to store date of same day in realm as a tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to store date object in realm the way you do it.

But you have a little typo in

```
dynamic var timeIn = NSData()
```

should be

```
dynamic var timeIn = NSDate()
```

Another possibility would be to store a time interval

```
dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
```

For more details have a look at the realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).